# Assistance require for css hover image

Tags: css

I am on the process in learning css.

I am trying to display the image in the middle of the screen upon user hover their mouse in the gallery.

however, the image hover within the image itself.
this is my code.

[jsfiddle.net/y9w5ym72/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/y9w5ym72/1/)

```
 body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: #EEE;
      font: 10px/13px 'Lucida Sans',sans-serif;
    }

.wrap {
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 50px;
    }

.box {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      width: 25%;
      padding-bottom: 25%;
      color: #FFF;

    }

.boxInner {
      position: absolute;
      left: 30px;
      right: 30px;
      top: 30px;
      bottom: 30px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background: #66F;

    }

.boxInner img {
      width: 100%;
    }




.thumbnail:hover img{
border: 1px solid transparent;
}


.thumbnail span{ 
position: absolute;
padding: 5px;
left: -1000px;
visibility: hidden;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}


.thumbnail span img{ 
border-width: 0;
width:70%; 
height: auto;
padding: 2px;
}

.thumbnail:hover span{ 

visibility: visible;
top: 0;
left: 230px; 
z-index: 50;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First point is you need to hide the first image. So that only you can see the second one. Second point is no need `position:absolute, left:-1000px;` styles for the inside span.

```
  .thumbnail:hover > img{
   border: 1px solid transparent;
   display:none;
  }


  .thumbnail span{ 
   /*position: absolute;
   left: -1000px;*/
   padding: 5px;
   visibility: hidden;
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
  }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y9w5ym72/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use position :absolute to achieve that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9w5ym72/4/)

```
.box:hover{position:absolute; top:38%; left:38%; z-index:200;}
```

Comment: with this method, why does the image go away when mouse over? Possible to make the image in the box stay and have the image hover in the middle ?

Comment: if that is the case you have to use 2 images because the box is fixed size image cant leave it